# How to retrieve a deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I asked a question at stackoverflow a while back with tag "antlr". Some guru in that topic believed my question was negative and marked so, as I recall, the question score is -2 or so.

Now I need to check out that question because there are some very useful information I referenced in the question, but to my surprise, I cannot find the question any more.

I just checked stackoverflow FAQ and realized that the system has the right to delete question deemed "unappropriated", geez! Anyway, is there a way I can retrieve the question? I have no intention to bring it up, just want that reference.

The following is from the FAQ, it seems I should be able to retrieve it, but not clear to me how.

> **What happens when a post is deleted?**
>
> Once a post has been deleted, it will disappear for all users except developers, moderators, and users with over 10,000 reputation. Deleted questions will also always be visible to their authors, regardless of the author's reputation. However, deleted posts can be undeleted by casting undelete votes. Once a post has 3 undelete votes, it will no longer be deleted.
>
> Self-deleted posts can be viewed, edited, and undeleted by their original authors.
>
> Please note that deleted questions do not appear in search results, so if you wish to later undelete a question that you've deleted you must have saved the URL somewhere.

I went over the list of my submitted questions, the question is not there, so I believe it is deleted by the system.

Comment: At the bottom of the questions list in your profile there should be a "recently deleted" link.

Comment: When you move a question from one site to another, please help clean up by deleting the question if you can on the site where it is off topic.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

If you did not save the direct link to the question; try the following, it might work as long as there is a reputation record for that question:

Go to your "[Reputation tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/255973/my-question?tab=reputation)" in your profile page, then click on the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of the page. Try to remember the date and expand the reputation details, you should be able to find it there somewhere.

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: This helped me find my deleted question. Thanks so much!